# php upload maximum size file using php.ini file and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

upgrade `upload_max_filesize`

> currently show 2M
>
> i Want To 50M

php.ini code

```
upload_max_filesize=30M;
```

.htaccess file code

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M
```

but these file is not work

if i upload .htaccess file then show 500 server error .

please sol this problem thanks .

Comment: i don't think you need to change the .htaccess file. possible solustion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Answer (score 1):

PHP has several configuration options to limit resources consumed by scripts. By default, PHP is set to allow uploads of files with a size of 2MB or less.

> Try increasing the following values in php.ini, for example:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 32M
post_max_size = 32M
```

Comment: @AdbulManan has probably diagnosed the problem correctly, so I would check that first. But another possibility is that your /tmp folder does not have the necessary free space to upload the file. Assuming your on a Linux environment, typing `df -h` from the command line should show you how much space you have left there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set those values only for specific project then do it in  **.htaccess** file otherwise set values in **php.ini** file

**.htaccess** file should be:-

```
php_value post_max_size 32M
php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
```

Comment: if i upload this file then show Internal Server Error .

Comment: put those lines after **RewriteEngine On** line

Comment: i also use this line on line no 1 .

Comment: Please show your entire .htaccess file in your question.

Answer (score 1):

set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini:

Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 50M

Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 50M